# C++ precision and truncation with file stream

Tags: c++, fstream, floating-point-precision, digits, truncation

I have a file.txt with hundreds of numbers. They have many digits (max 20) after the point and I need to get them all without truncation, otherwise they introduce errors in the following computations. I made these numbers with matlab so it has a monstrous precision but now I must replicate this behaviour in my program.

I've done this way:

```
 fstream in;
 in.open(file.txt, ios::in);
 long double number;
 in>>number;
```

I also tried this

```
 in.precision(20);
 in>>number;
```

before each ">>" operation but it is vain.

If I copy and paste these numbers in my code assigning them to long double variables all goes well as it were matlab. It's a problem of functions or fstream, not precision of long double type, isn't it?

For examples, take this number 2.7239385667867091 and save it in a file.txt. Can you read all its digits with C++ and fstream?

Comment: Why do you post a duplication of a question you just asked? If you want to add something, edit your original question.

Comment: no one is answering and I need a help

Comment: If you exceed [max_digits10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) then the trailing digits will be suspect.